# unable to view ajax response in chrome dev tools

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to view the AJAX response in Chrome DevTools. However, I'm greeted with, "the request has no response data available." Am I doing something wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Here's the request (I'm always greeted with the "response false" alert, even if it's a valid email address. Hence, my trying to troubleshoot. However, I'll leave that for another question):

```
$("#email_address").on("keyup", function() {
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'verify_email.php',
        data: {email: $("#email_address").val(),
               submitted: true},
        type: 'post'
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
        if(response == true) {
            alert("response true");
        } else if(response == false) {
            alert("response false");
        } else {
            alert("heh?");
        }
    });

    request.error(function(response) {
        alert("an error occurred");
    });
});
```

Here's my verify_email.php code that's called with the AJAX request, if it helps at all:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How are you making that request??

Comment: good point. I've elaborated on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo 'true';
            return true;
        } else {
            echo 'false';
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

I've never used `and` in an `if()` myself (does it work?). Probably not your problem though ...

You're not echoing anything onto the page so you're return a page that's got no response data to show.

Comment: ok, that answered/fixed both of my problems. still getting used to how this all works. thx

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!